# Load data on ajax for Row expander in ExtJs

Tags: ajax, extjs

I am using Sencha ExtJs grid 4.2 . I am using a Expander plugins for my grid and try to load data under expanded region from Ajax. Right now I am using this code to show data on expanding.

```
plugins: [{
    ptype: 'rowexpander',
    rowBodyTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<br><img height="31" width="32" src="../upload/patient/thumb/{patient_image}">',
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p><b>{fname}, {lname}</b></p>',
        '<br> {accordian_view}'
    )
}],
```

Here you can see that data is pre populated, but my requirement is to load data on expanding. I am trying hard to find the event or process to do it. But still no luck. If anyone have any idea please share.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the `expandbody` event on the RowExpander plugin: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander-event-expandbody

This event passes not only the row's bound record, but also the expanded  element, so you could:

- Request data via Ext.Ajax.request({...})
- Handle response
- Add content to expanded row

One thing to keep in mind, however, is the async nature of this approach. That is, the row is going to expand *immediately*, regardless of how long the subsequent request takes to come back. So it would probably be a good idea to do something like this instead when handling the `expandbody` event:

- Add "loading" text/icon/whatever into expanded row area
- Make Ajax request
- Handle response
- Replace loading text/icon/whatever with the data returned from the Ajax request

It's likely someone has already done so, but you could also (and I would highly suggest it) wrap this process into a custom plugin of your own that extends the RowPlugin. That way you could use it elsewhere in your app for any grid. If you end up creating a custom plugin, please share it with the community!

EDIT: A quick Google revealed a number of custom plugins that do precisely this. For example: https://github.com/nickbretz/Ext.ux.AsyncRowExpander/blob/master/AsyncRowExpander.js

Comment: Saddly this AsyncRowExpander plugin doesnt work with 4.2.1 :(